# Склонение слов

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, есть код.

```
<?php

if (!defined('DATALIFEENGINE')) {
    die('Доступ ограничен!');
}

$allcount = dle_cache('news_count');
if(empty($allcount)){
    $allcount = $db->super_query("SELECT count(*) as c FROM ".PREFIX."_post WHERE approve");
    $allcount = $allcount['c'];
    create_cache('news_count',$allcount);
}

function declOfNumallcount($numcount, $titlescount) {
    $casescount = array (2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2);
    return $numcount." ".$titlescount[($numcount%100>4 && $numcount%100<20)? 2 : $casescount[min($numcount%10, 5)]];
}

echo declOfNumallcount('<span>'.$allcount.'</span>', array('<font>материал</font>', '<font>материала</font>', '<font>материалов</font>'));

?>
```

Может, что не так сделал, но при значении 122 он выводит слово *материалов*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Проверяйте](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fa419d05e54307746bf2c171f50d29ee4cc2e722)

**UPDATE #1:**

```
echo declOfNumallcount($allcount, array('материал', 'материала', 'материалов'));
```

**UPDATE #2:**

```
function declOfNumallcount($numcount, $titlescount) {
    $casescount = array (2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2);
    return $titlescount[($numcount%100>4 && $numcount%100<20)? 2 : $casescount[min($numcount%10, 5)]];
}

$allcount = 122;
$endWord = declOfNumallcount($allcount , array('', 'а', 'ов'));
echo "{$allcount} <div>материал{$endWord}</div>";
```

или же [sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b1c622394a2cfa6674306b41ec9ff753d5e394ff)

Повторюсь, [не используйте `<font>`](http://htmlbook.ru/html/font).

Comment: Не очень дружу с php, можете все это соединить?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /home/m17275/public_html/site.ru/engine/modules/all_material.php on line 15

Comment: У Вас версия PHP ниже 5.4. Исправил ответ.

Comment: @malcov, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

И это же правило касается вопроса [заданного Вами ранее](http://hashcode.ru/questions/391940/php-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B5)

Comment: Ошибка осталась

Comment: Не верю!. [Жмите `Execute code` и проверяйте](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/384ac1fcc8e9fa831c629a9c1b95bd7f0a56afb0).

Comment: Во, заработало, т.е это все из за тега font? а если мне нужно его использовать. И именно только на цифре

Comment: @malcov Обновил ответ.